# Activity doesn't open when the user taps on the notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

In my app main activity doesn't open when the user taps on the notification

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission android:name="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags.ActivityPrincipal" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags.ActivityPrincipal.NOTIFICATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity" />
        <service android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="mx.com.eluniversal.test.pruebapushtags" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

It doesn't open if the app is on the background and doesn't update the information in the activity while in the foreground when a new push notification arrives.

Comment: is that a hybrid or native application?

Comment: is native application with push notification with tags

Comment: @JaiveTorresPineda, can you add to the question the content of strings.xml? Please respond.

Comment: @JaiveTorresPineda, if you would like help with this question, you need to respond... can you add to the question the content of strings.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following Native Android sample application that demonstrates implementing Tag-based push notifications: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notification-native-android-applications/tag-based-notifications/

Compare its files with yours (AndroidManifest.xml, strings.xml, ...).
Since you are not responding in the comments, that's the best that can be done at this time.

Note: This application is based on MobileFirst Platform 7.0, so you cannot open the project file in previous releases. However, you can still extract the .zip file and look at the source files from the file system.